# Swift stdlib tool Error -> Task failed with exit 1 signal - IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to launch my developed app on my iphone and I am getting a build fail with the following error.  I do not know how to address the problem.  Please can someone advise?  I can build the app on the simulator but not on the iphone.

```
 error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
/usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' 'CF34DF6AAC83D040CB9CA5907F171518DB7A331F' '--verbose' '/Users/johnDow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-dfuggtbkfdkixtemtcsnzflclljy/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the derived Data

```
rm -rf /Users/johnDow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

If that doesn't work I had to re install xcode AND restart computer to fix it